# Prior art which discloses less than 2mg of prednisone used for treatment of arthritis

Tags: drug-ingredients, medicine, us6677326

Which is the closest prior art for this patent which discloses less than 2mg of prednisone used for treatment of arthritis? The list of documents in hit results includes [US6677326](http://www.google.com/patents/US6677326) patent European equivalents.

Comment: What is the patent number for the patent you are asking the question about?

Answer (score 1):

See this:

[SMALL DOSES OF PREDNISOLONE IN THE
MANAGEMENT OF RHEUMATOID ARTHRITIS](http://ard.bmj.com/content/23/2/158.full.pdf)

from 1964...